wait for context to be updated when using SwiftData
How would you wait for the context to be updated before continuing?
import SwiftData
@State var selectedItem: Item?
@Query var items: [Item]

    func addItem() {
        let item = Item()
        context.insert(item)
        selectedItem = item
        print(items)
    }

result: []
desired: [Item]
    func deleteItem(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for index in offsets {
            context.delete(items[index])
        }
        if items.isEmpty || items.contains(where: { $0.id == selectedItem?.id }) == false {
            selectedItem = nil
        }
    }

since the context isn't updated at the time of the if statement, it never runs as expected.

Why not get hold of the index of the selected item first and clear the selection if it's part of the deleted objects.
if let selectedIndex = items.firstIndex(where { $0.id == selectedItem?.id }, offsets.contains(selectedIndex) {
    selectedItem = nil
} 

// delete loop...

